# HTTP Error when trying to download MNIST data

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using Google Colab for training a LeNet-300-100 fully-connected neural network on MNIST using Python3 and PyTorch 1.8.

To apply the transformations and download the MNIST dataset, the following code is being used:

```
# MNIST dataset statistics:
# mean = tensor([0.1307]) & std dev = tensor([0.3081])
mean = np.array([0.1307])
std_dev = np.array([0.3081])

transforms_apply = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean = mean, std = std_dev)
    ])
```

which gives the error:

> Downloading
> http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz to
> ./data/MNIST/raw/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 2 train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
> 3         root = './data', train = True,
> ----> 4         transform = transforms_apply, download = True
> 5         )
> 6
>
> 11 frames /usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in
> http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
> 647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
> 648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
> --> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> 650
> 651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):
>
> HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

What's wrong?

Comment: `http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz` is throwing a `503` error, so you won't be able to download it. You could try getting it from another source, eg. `!wget -P ./data/MNIST/raw/ https://github.com/zalandoresearch/fashion-mnist/raw/master/data/fashion/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Is it possible that this is due to Google Colab's backend?

Comment: No this is a server-side error of `http://yann.lecun.com`. You can't fix that ,so try to load the data from another source

Answer (score 18):

I was having the same 503 error and this worked for me

```
!wget www.di.ens.fr/~lelarge/MNIST.tar.gz
!tar -zxvf MNIST.tar.gz

from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torchvision import transforms

train_set = MNIST('./', download=True,
transform=transforms.Compose([
transforms.ToTensor(),
]), train=True)


test_set = MNIST('./', download=True,
transform=transforms.Compose([
transforms.ToTensor(),
]), train=False)
```

Comment: For window users, just go to www.di.ens.fr/~lelarge/MNIST.tar.gz, download it, and unzip the file. Then you will have MNIST folder, which you put into the root directory for dataloader.

Answer (score 6):

There has been a lot of trouble with the MNIST hosted on http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ therefore pytorch got permission and hosting it now on amazon aws.

Unfortunately, the fix is only available in the nightly build ([Here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/ddad38f3a84d4d87cbb389bc78e245920fe86f82/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py#L33) you can find the fixed code. )

A hot fix I found useful is:

```
from torchvision import datasets
new_mirror = 'https://ossci-datasets.s3.amazonaws.com/mnist'
datasets.MNIST.resources = [
   ('/'.join([new_mirror, url.split('/')[-1]]), md5)
   for url, md5 in datasets.MNIST.resources
]
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
   "../data", train=True, download=True, transform=transform
)
```

**Update**: According to [torch vision issue 3549](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/3549) this will be fixed in the next minor release

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been solved in `torchvision==0.9.1` according to [this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/3549#issuecomment-797265911). As a temporary solution, please use the following workaround:

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
datasets.MNIST.resources = [
    ('https://ossci-datasets.s3.amazonaws.com/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', 'f68b3c2dcbeaaa9fbdd348bbdeb94873'),
    ('https://ossci-datasets.s3.amazonaws.com/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'd53e105ee54ea40749a09fcbcd1e9432'),
    ('https://ossci-datasets.s3.amazonaws.com/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz', '9fb629c4189551a2d022fa330f9573f3'),
    ('https://ossci-datasets.s3.amazonaws.com/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz', 'ec29112dd5afa0611ce80d1b7f02629c')
]

# AND the rest of your code as usual for train and test (EXAMPLE):
batch_sz = 100
tr_ = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])
# MNIST
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
    root='./dataset', 
    train=True, 
    transform=tr_,  
    download=True
)

test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
    root='./dataset', 
    train=False, 
    transform=tr_  
)
# DataLoader
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset=train_dataset,
    batch_size=batch_sz,
    shuffle=True 
)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset=test_dataset,
    batch_size=batch_sz,
    shuffle=False 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml


mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', data_home=".")

x = mnist.data
x = x.reshape((-1, 28, 28))
x = x.astype('float32')

y = mnist.target
y = y.astype('float32')
```

Answer (score 1):

For PyTorch 0.4.0 in udacity notebooks.

The solution is inspired by the above solution.

```py
new_mirror = 'https://ossci-datasets.s3.amazonaws.com/mnist'
datasets.MNIST.urls = [
   str('/'.join([new_mirror, url.split('/')[-1]]))
   for url in datasets.MNIST.urls
]
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,)),
                                ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

use that

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong. It is problem of the platform where data is hosted.
Using Pytorch you can download MNIST using below code

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST

# Download training dataset
dataset = MNIST(root='data/', download=True)
```

The above MNIST wrapper in Pytorch datasets would try many possible places where data is available. After running the code you can see that first it tries to download from Yan Le Cun site but fails to download from there and fall back to other possible options.

Potential Cause: The Yan LeCun Site is missing an updated SSL certificate, so some methods of downloading files do consider about this security measure and some doesn't.